# How to update data into another page using smart table in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in my angular project. Smart table is providing built-in add, edit and delete data but I don't want to use it. I want to edit data on another page, like we do for every CRUD operation. I have searched it but I did not find any solution. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to make your custom icon with edit icon and put in action. For that block/deactive default edit button.

With that you will get your click event in `(custom)="customeEdit($event)"`.

By this way you can use your custom component in `ng2-smart-table`.

[Add custom icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687398/8612835)

Comment: Hey, @Sachin Shah it is working but i am not able to add multiple custom buttons in table

Comment: @KinjalVithalani You have to add your all custom buttons in `custom[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect user by binding a method to (edit) event. like this.

**.html**

```
<ng2-smart-table  class="table"
                          [settings]="settings" 
                          [source]="data" 
                          (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
                          (rowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" 
                          (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)"
                          (rowHover)="onRowHover($event)"
                          (create)="onCreateNewProcessor($event)"
                          (edit)="onEditData($event)"
                          (custom)="onCustom($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

**.ts**

```
onEditData(event) {
    this.router.navigate(["/route/i/want/to", event.data.id]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I have tried it. It's not working!  @Yoarthur

Comment: import { VisitGymModule } from './smart-table-demo/smart-table.module' into the router app.module. And also fix the bugs you've and send me the link again.

Comment: I have added module in app.module.ts still not working. And also I have added dependency for smart table then also it is not importing properly!  @Yoarthur